# QGIS field calculator: Change start value for @row_number

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, sequential

So I can use the @row_number function to number sequentially but I want my start value to be 27, not 1. 
Is there some bit of code i need to use, where I can change the start value?

Comment: What software are you using? What have you tried so far?

Comment: QGIS 3.0 i know how to do it in ESRI, but can't see how to change the starting value from 1

Comment: @row_number + 26

Answer (score 9):

To increase the starting value of a variable, use addition.

```
@row_number + 26
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with python parser

```
rec=0  
def autoIncrement():  
 global rec  
 pStart = 1 #adjust start value, if req'd   
 pInterval = 1 #adjust interval value, if req'd  
 if (rec == 0):   
  rec = pStart   
 else:   
  rec = rec + pInterval   
 return rec
```

Then type the name of the function into the textbox below the code block:

```
autoIncrement()
```

Source: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011137

Comment: This appears to be for ArcGIS rather than the requested QGIS. Also, it is always good (and expected) to credit those that you copied and pasted their code: e.g. https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011137.