# Adding id values in attribute table after digitization

Tags: qgis-3, attribute-table, null

I have digitized land use and land cover polygons and am curious as to why the `"id"` attribute (presumably automatically assigned and populated) is either `NULL` or blank for my polygons.

Geometric validation reports feature `"id"`s, but I cannot relate them to my data. Is there a way to automatically set the `"id"`s?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following field calculator expression to calculate the feature id:

```py
 $id
```

You can use the following field calculator expression to calculate the row number:

```py
 @row_number
```

---

**References:**

- [Is there a way of auto_increment for the ID column in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132346/is-there-a-way-of-auto-increment-for-the-id-column-in-qgis)
- [Fill with @row_number based on group field in QGIS 3?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286229/fill-with-row-number-based-on-group-field-in-qgis-3)
- [QGIS field calculator: Change start value for @row_number](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277506/qgis-field-calculator-change-start-value-for-row-number/277525)

Comment: Thanks. So the id is simply the row number?  What happens if I delete a feature? Are the ids re-shuffled?

Comment: Unless you create a new unique id field and assign a unique id to each feature, the row_number as well as the feature id will be 'reshuffled' when you add or delete features

Comment: I added some another calc for the feature id

Comment: P.S. @jbalk, sorry that I interfered in your answer, however, I found these sources vital and most likely relate to the topic.

Comment: @Taras That's ok.  Those are good extras.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks fro the responses.  I will try the field calculator solutions.