# In the QGIS error message "Feature (99) has invalid geometry" does the 99 refer to the OBJECTID?

Tags: qgis, geometry, simplify

QGIS 3.4.2-Madeira running simplify on a polygon z shapefile with 1075 rows. `"Feature (99) has invalid geometry"` not sure how to find this feature. If I edit and delete the row with `OBJECTID = 99` and rerun simplify the same error presents but lists `Feature(98)` as invalid.

Interestingly running Geometry Tools\ Check Validity returns no errors and no invalid output, but if I run the fix geometries tool and then run simplify on the Fixed geometries layer then simplify works fine.

Key question I have is how to identify (and fix) the problem geometry for "Feature 99". Does the 99 refer to the `OBJECTID`?

Comment: It refers to the feature id. Your objectid can be something different. But you could also set your processing tools to ignore invalid inputs.

Comment: Thanks MrX. I now understand that the Feature ID is only available if it is explicitly added to the Attribute table. My question and the solution appear to be identical to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/336702/adding-id-values-in-attribute-table-after-digitization. By adding a new column with $id I was able to identify which row related to feature id 99.

Answer (score 3):

`Feature (99)` **refers to the feature id** with the number 99. In PyQGIS this would be identical to `feature.id() == 99` and in fieldcalculator identical to `$id = 99`.

Your `OBJECTID` is just a field. It can contain anything. We dont know what that actually is.

To find your `Feature (99)` create a new field with the expression `$id`.

---

An alternative would be to set your processing tools to **ignore invalid inputs**. Go to "Settings" --> "Options" --> "Processing" and change "Invalid features filtering" to "Skip (ignore) features with invalid geometries":

[image]